# Python split function won't work on list to generate list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I am learning python and did the following experiement.

```
    text = "this is line one . this is line two . this is line three ."
    
    tokens = text.split(" ")            # split text into token with seperator "space"
    lioftokens = tokens.split(".")      # split tokens into list of tokens with seperator "dot"
    
    print(tokens)                       # output = ['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']
    print(lioftokens)                   # expected output = [['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'],
                                        #                    ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'],
                                        #                    ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']]
```

It gives error instead of expected output.

The `split()` is for string, not for list.
How should I solve it?

#IamNewToPython

Comment: `tokens.split(".")` doesn't work because `split` is to split string into lists but `tokens` is a list not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `list` comprehension:

```
text = "this is line one . this is line two . this is line three ."
print([line.rstrip().split() for line in text.split('.') if line])
```

Output:

```
[['this', 'is', 'line', 'one'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three']]
```

If you want to keep the splitters try:

```
import re
text = "this is line one . this is line two . this is line three ."
print([line.rstrip().split() for line in re.split('([^\.]*\.)', text) if line])
```

Output:

```
[['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']]
```

**Edit:**

If you want to do list split try:

```
l = ['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']
newl = [[]]
for i in l:
    newl[-1].append(i)
    if i == '.':
        newl.append([])
print(newl)
```

Output:

```
[['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.'], []]
```

Comment: The main concern is to convert

['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']

into list of list 

[['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']]

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad Done. Please check my **Edit:** part, remember to accept and upvote if it works

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> text = "this is line one . this is line two . this is line three ."
>>> list(filter(None, map(str.split, text.split("."))))
[['this', 'is', 'line', 'one'],
 ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two'],
 ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three']]
```

You can simply split the list by `.` first, then simply `map` a `str.split` to each individual string inside the list.

Comment: The OP wants the period to be preserved in the output.

Comment: The main concern is to convert  ['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']  into list of list  [['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']]

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "this is line one . this is line two . this is line three ."

# first split on the periods
sentences = text.split('.')

for s in sentences:
    # chop off trailing whitespace and then split on spaces
    print(s.rstrip().split())
```

Comment: The OP wants the period to be preserved in the output.

Comment: The main concern is to convert  ['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']  into list of list  [['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']]

Answer (score 0):

str.split() method.

```
text = "this is line one . this is line two . this is line three ."

print([text.split()[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(text.split()),5) ])
```

Comment: The main concern is to convert  ['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.', 'this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']  into list of list  [['this', 'is', 'line', 'one', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'two', '.'], ['this', 'is', 'line', 'three', '.']]